# Enable geolocation in Capybara / Selenium / ChromeDriver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, geolocation, selenium-chromedriver

Does anyone know how to test a Rails app with geolocation?
I have tried with this setup, but it crashes.

**spec_helper.rb**

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium2

Capybara.register_driver :selenium2 do |app|
  prefs = {
    :geolocation => {
      :default_content_setting => true, 
    }
  }
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end
```

**$ rspec ./spec/acceptance/create_new_account_spec.rb**

```
 Failure/Error: visit login_page
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
   unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
   from tab crashed
     (Session info: chrome=33.0.1750.152)
     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248307,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.2 x86_64)
```

I'm using this versions:

- selenium-webdriver (2.40.0)
- Chrome 34.0.1847.76
- chromedriver 2.9.248307

Comment: Can you stub out the geolocation settings?

Comment: I guess I could, but from what I understand it is possible to activate geolocation with selenium. Not sure how I can stub it out.

Comment: What would it return? user.stub(:geolocation).and_return(geolocation_value) But it sounds like there's a selenium setting. I didn't know that.